# send image in img tag on form submit and as email attachment

Tags: php

I want to send image in img tag as email attachment in php.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
        <img src="image full path" id="ImgSrc1" name="ImgSrc1"/>
        <img src="image full path" id="ImgSrc2" name="ImgSrc2"/>
</form>
```

I want to send these multiple image as email attachment in PHP.

Form tag is written in HTML file and PHP email attachment code is on another server. I am using jQuery submit for submitting this code. All other details in the form tag are going correctly but i am not sure , how to send images. As below.

```
var postData = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    url:"server url /mailAttachment.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : postData,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }           
});
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: If the image is from the same host (due to same-origin policy), you can load it into a canvas and afterwards access the image data and send it using AJAX (e.g. via FormData). jQuery won't help you much with it though.

Comment: The `<img>` element is for displaying an image in the page, not for describing form data. If you know the path already, then there is no need to include it in the page at all - you can just write PHP to include it in the email. If you want the user to pick it then you need a file input and then to read up on how to send files with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: image is on a mobile device and i am sending server request to execute php code on other server.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. But my requirement is that. it is a mobile app from where i am capturing image through camera and showing that image in img tag. hence i need that image in img tag to be send as attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by including the image data within the email. You can do this by encoding the image with `base64_encode()`. You would include the data within the email's content for the `mail()` function in PHP

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('logo.gif'));" />
```

However I would reconmend to use an alternate liabry such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send the email as it is more robust and a lot more powerful.